# Windows command to find a specific string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a requirement to fetch the specific details from the cmd output. For example if I do a tnsping as below it will return a value something like this

`tnsping <TNS_NAME>`

```
 E:\Temp>tnsping db1

 TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 21-NOV-2019 11:30:26

 Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Used parameter files:
 E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (description = (load_balance = off) (failover = on) (address = (protocol = 
tcp)(HOST = 100.200.300.20)(PORT = 1530)) (address = (protocol = tcp)(HOST = 100.200.300.40)(PORT = 
1530)) (connect_timeout = 5) (transport_connect_timeout = 3) (connect_data = (server = dedicated) 
(service_name = <Service_db1>)))
OK (10 msec)
```

So, my requirement is to fetch only the 1st occurrence of the HOST value only which is `100.200.300.20` in doc bat scripting.

Any suggestion how this can be achieved?

Comment: Why tag this [tag:findstr] if you never use `findstr` anywhere? My suggestion how it can be achieved: use `findstr`. Not the answer you expect, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not `tnsping`, so I copied your output example in a file and wrote this working Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "HOST" test.txt') do set "line=%%a"

:next
for /F "tokens=1* delims=()" %%a in ("%line%") do set "token=%%a" & set "line=%%b"
for /F "tokens=1,3" %%a in ("%token%") do (
   if "%%a" equ "HOST" set "HOST=%%b" & goto exit
)
goto next

:exit

echo HOST=%HOST%
```

You should store `tnsping` output in the file via `tnsping db1 > test.txt`, or take it directly in the `for` command this way:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('tnsnping db1 ^| findstr "HOST"') do set "line=%%a"
```

Comment: Great Thanks.. !! I have used this `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('tnsnping db1 ^| findstr "HOST"') do set "line=%%a"` and its working and served my purpose.